# Validating Null and 0

Tags: java, validation, null

I am developing a small validator in java. I would like to validate if the input value is 0 or simply empty. If its empty or 0 i would like to get an exception. So my code is looking, i know it isn't finishe, but i don't know how to realize it. Thanks for the help!

```
public boolean isValid(final AbstractObject value) {
        if (value instanceof Bank) {
            final Bank bank = (Bank) value;

            final ApplicationContext appContext = this.getApplicationContext();
            final BankService service = (BankService) appContext.getBean("myStoreService");


            final Map<String, Object> namedParam = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            namedParam.put(Bank.PROPERTY_IBAN, bank.getIban());
            namedParam.put(Bank.PROPERTY_BIC, bank.getBix());
            namedParam.put(PersistentObject.PARAMETER_DIFFERENT_STATUS, PersistentObject.STATUS_DELETED);

            final Integer count = service.countBankByQuery(namedParam);
            if (count <= 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: if (value == 0 )){throw new Exception("error")};

Comment: An `Integer` can't be empty but `null`. So `if( count == null || count == 0)` should do it.

Comment: by "empty"  do you mean null??

Comment: Yes that was my thoughts, that empty is null.

Comment: what if the value is "    "?

Comment: Then the two answers are correct. I didn't use the `Optional` as a choice, I find that a bit verbose for that simple case but it works too

Comment: with if( count == null || count == 0) and if i'm tipping an 11 in the box, i get the IllegalArgumentException which i implemented. Maybe this exception is wrong?!

Comment: @sportsbettor remember to accept the answer that fit the most the problem to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you code

```
final Integer count = service.countBankByQuery(namedParam);
if (count <= 0) {
    return false;
}
```

An `Integer` can't be "empty" but can be `null`.

So just check those to possible value

```
if( count == null || count == 0)
```

Note : 
Be careful that `count == 0` should throw a `NullPointerException` if you don't check if it is not `null` as it would actually be `count.intValue() == 0`, a method can't be call on a null instance.

Comment: If i'm trying your version i receive the exception if i am writing an 11 in the fields. But cant understand why. if (count == null || count == 0) {
    throw new NullPointerException("ERROR!");
   }

Comment: @sportsbettor Check the `count` value, it doesn't make sense to entered the block with a value like `11`

Comment: But i need this. If i' enter a simple integer everything should be okay, The user should only be informed if he entered a 0

Comment: @sportsbettor that's why I asked you to check if the value `count` was `11`, not to ignore that ;) the condition I wrote should only be true if you have a `null` or `0`. `11` should not enter the condition block. You could update your question with the code you have write.

Comment: @sportsbettor What was it ? I could add this to the solution

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 solution:

```
final Integer count = service.countBankByQuery(namedParam);

if (Optional.ofNullable(count).orElse(0).intValue() == 0) {
    throw new Excepton();
}
```

Java alternative solution with Guava Optional:

```
final Integer count = service.countBankByQuery(namedParam);

if (Optional.fromNullable(count).or(0).intValue() == 0) {
    throw new Excepton();
}
```

Or write your own generified object wrapper class i.e.:

```
public class MyOptional<T> implements Serializable...
```

Comment: The method ofNullable is undefined for Integer.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Where i find Optional?

Comment: java.util.Optional, Java 8. If you are using Java 7, then look for Guava Optional as an external dependency.

Comment: Guava optional doesn't have ofNullable and orElse

Comment: Yes, guavas method names are slightly different: Optional.fromNullable(count).or(0).intValue() == 0

Comment: Now i get the classnotfound Exception, but i am import this: com.google.common.base.Optional;

Comment: What class exactly is missing? Maybe you should do the clean install procedure.

Comment: The optional class is missing, although i imported it

Comment: Did you add it into classpath? Or maven dependency?

Comment: @sportsbettor To be honest, adding a dependencies just to get one class, that could be written easily yourself, is not necessary for a simple case like this.

Comment: Actually, AxelH is making sense. If it is a small project there is no need to drag external dependencies in.

Comment: @ArtyomRebrov still valid for Java 8, so you should add this condition in the answer ;) and the possible alternative before java 8.

Answer (score -1):

you need check the value first judge if `value==0` or `value==null` and then 
throw `new Exception()`

Answer (score -1):

You should create a "custom"  [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and check if it's empty

Here's Exception to work with your actual code, just create a new Class and put that code inside, it's just a constructor who ask for a String

```
public class emptyOrZeroIntegerException extends Exception{

    public emptyOrZeroIntegerException()
    {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public emptyOrZeroIntegerException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Here's your code modified to work with Exception

```
  public boolean isValid(final AbstractObject value) throws emptyOrZeroIntegerException {
            if (value instanceof Bank) {
                final Bank bank = (Bank) value;

                final ApplicationContext appContext = this.getApplicationContext();
                final BankService service = (BankService) appContext.getBean("myStoreService");


                final Map<String, Object> namedParam = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                namedParam.put(Bank.PROPERTY_IBAN, bank.getIban());
                namedParam.put(Bank.PROPERTY_BIC, bank.getBix());
                namedParam.put(PersistentObject.PARAMETER_DIFFERENT_STATUS, PersistentObject.STATUS_DELETED);


                final Integer count = service.countBankByQuery(namedParam);

                //Check if empty here and throw new Exception
                if (count <= 0) {
                    throw new emptyOrZeroIntegerException("Number not valid");
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
```

Comment: If i'm writing so, then i get the excpeption thrown:if (count <= 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR!");
   }

Comment: Did you create emptyOrZeroIntegerException?

Comment: Yes but then i receive: Exception emptyOrZeroIntegerException is not compatible with throws clause in BankBasedValidator.isValid(AbstractObject)

Comment: It's hard to tell without full code, but I'm guessing you didnt add throws clause at declaration of method Ex: public boolean... throws emptyOrZeroIntegerException.

Comment: If i add the throws clause, then i get this error: Exception emptyOrZeroIntegerException is not compatible with throws clause in BankBasedValidator.isValid(AbstractObject)